# Зажатие клавиши в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.7

```
...
import pygame
if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
    print ("Hello")
...
```

написал так. А выводит ошибку:

```
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'key'
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить `from pygame.locals import *` и добавить экран. Без экрана не работает (я не разбирался в этом - может можно и без экрана, но зачем использовать pygame и не создавать окно?)

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import * #это добавляет обработку клавиш
pygame.init() #инициализация окна
W = 700  
H = 300  
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))#установка размера окна
clock = pygame.time.Clock()#время (не обязательно)
while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get(): #обработка нажатия на крестик (выход)
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        print ("Hello")

    clock.tick(60) # частота обновления экрана (FPS) - не обязательно
    # но если не добавить ограничение - сильно возрастает нагрузка на процессор
    # чем меньше FPS - тем медленнее печатается Hello
    pygame.event.pump()
```

Comment: я писал в начале экран. Там же стоит три точки вначале

Answer (score 0):

будет выдавать ошибку если вы не добавите  это:

```
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))#размер можете поменять
```

Тогда окно откроется и закроется для этого нужно сделать цикл.
Весь код

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        print('Hello')
```

Comment: я писал в начале размер. Там же стоит три точки вначале